# blender serial communication is lagging

Tags: python, scripting

I wanted to stream a quaternions from my mpu into blender the problem is the thing is very laggy the animation itself looks smooth the problem is with the serial data for example:-

after I roll the mpu by 60 degrees in my hand I see the result like 2 to 5 seconds after the result is smooth but very late the values in the prints seem to be the one that lags in the change  also the problem is only with blender when running putty for example the data updates just fine

I tried decreasing the time interval with no luck

also for some reason I don't understand but maybe worth mentioning the code runs perfectly fine if I just opened the computer or something it's also worth mentioning that removing the print statements did nothing

I used the Modal operator code provided by blender and modified it to read my quat and update a small cube for now

````
import bpy
from mathutils import Quaternion
from bpy.props import BoolProperty
import serial


object_name = "Cube"  # Replace with the name of your object
obj = bpy.data.objects[object_name]
obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'

#FPS = 30        # use 30 if system performance is poor
FPS = 60
#FPS = 90
#FPS = 360

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
ser.flushInput()

def print(data):
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'CONSOLE':
                override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
                bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(override, text=str(data), type="OUTPUT")
                
                





def read_quat():
    dataPacket = ser.readline()
    dataPacket = str(dataPacket, 'utf-8')
    numbers = dataPacket.split("\t")

    if(len(numbers) != 4):
        return
    
    w = (numbers[0])
    x = (numbers[1])
    y = (numbers[2])
    z = (numbers[3])
    
  
    z = z.strip('\x00\n')

    try:
        w = float(w)
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        z = float(z)
    except ValueError:
        return
    
    quat = [w, x, y, z]
    return quat

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs itself from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            self.update_orientation(context)  
            #quaternion_values = read_quat()
            #if quaternion_values is not None:
             #   print(quaternion_values)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def update_orientation(self, context):
        if obj is None:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, f"Object '{object_name}' not found.")
            self.running = False
            return

        quaternion_values = read_quat()
        if quaternion_values is None:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Invalid quaternion values.")
            return

        quaternion = Quaternion(quaternion_values)
        obj.rotation_quaternion = quaternion
        
    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1/FPS, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalTimerOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalTimerOperator.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Modal Timer Operator" for quick access).
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()

```
````